# Display graphics with raspberry pi and windows 10 iot

Tags: c#

can someone give me a hint how I can display a line or bar charts with Visual Studio (Windows 10 iot - Raspberry PI) in either C # or Visual Basic or via XAML. The data for the graph (line) must be dependent on input from an array. Thank you.

Comment: Bar charts - and maybe even graphs - can be made with some [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) if you run out of options...

Comment: You have to write WinForm or WPF application (not sure which is supported for IoT).

Answer (score 5):

**If you are looking for something like the following kind of UI for Windows IoT, follow the steps I've provided:**
[image]

This is what you are looking for "WinRT XAML Toolkit (UWP)":
https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

I've provided the sample project of "Windows IoT and WinRT XAML Toolkit - Chart" ([download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCCbOj3fbZGNXhGc3c0M3YtYUU/view?usp=sharing))

> Make sure to rebuild provided project.

**How to use "WinRT XAML Toolkit (UWP)" in Windows IoT?**
Create new "Blank App (Universal Windows)"
**Step 1: Open NuGet Package Manager** [image: NuGet Package Manager]
**Step 2: Search and Install "WinRT XAML Toolkit"** [image: WinRT XAML Toolkit UWP]
**Step 3: Review Changes**[image: Review Changes]

**Now you are able to use WinRT XAML Toolkit into your Windows IoT project:**
[image: Charting in Windows IoT]

**[Download the source code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCCbOj3fbZGNXhGc3c0M3YtYUU/view?usp=sharing)**(Make sure to rebuild provided project.)
**Feel free to ask for any issue.**

> Learn more about "WinRT XAML Toolkit" at:
>  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/02/14/an-overview-of-ui-controls-from-win-rt-xaml-toolkit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can write a WPF application(WPF surely work for IoT),
and you can use this tutorial for draw a line:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trTTQWd8OUE

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an universal app using vs2015 and windows10 
Follow this sample [Hello world raspbery pie!](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/HelloWorld.htm) , and then add the graphics code of your flavor